# Hyperbolic conservation laws with integral source term

Tags: hyperbolic-equations

Suppose

$u_t+\alpha u_x =\int\limits_{b-h}^{b} u(t,x) dx $

$u=u(x,t), (x,t)\in ([a,b]\times [0,T])$

with initial data $ u(x,0)=u_0(x)$, h is fixed xonstant.
I want to solve this equation by using finite volume method (FVM). I can apply   FVM  for  such type of conservation laws with source term like 
$ u_t+au_x=S(u,x,t)$.
But if $S(u,x,t)=\int\limits_{b-h}^{b} u(t,x) dx $
I have no idea how to tackle the right-hand side of the above differential equation.
Can you provide me some suggestion.

Comment: In the present case, the source term $S(u,x,t) = \int_{b-h}^b u(t,x)\, dx$ is actually only dependent on time. Just proceed as usual with [FV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_volume_method) methods: integrate the equation in time over $[t_1,t_2]$ and in space over $[x_{i-1/2},x_{i+1/2}]$.

Comment: What you are presenting is actually a balance law, not a conservation law.